# What does "Unable to coerce to Series, length must be 1: given 11" error mean in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to plot the fall of an object (an optical fork to be precise) as a function of time in order to verify that the law of gravity is indeed 9.81.
The different data are supposed to represent the passage at each slot. The different slits are spaced 1 centimeter apart and there are 11 slits in all. I measured these data with an Arduino setup and I plot the graph and fit with Python. I have the data in a CSV file but when I run my code, I get an error "Unable to coerce to Series, length must be 1: given 11". However, when I enter the values manually one by one instead of reading the file, the code works and I get this graph, which is what I expect.

[image: graph]

Here is the instruction I use (I added the values at each iteration by entering them manually and I thought that by doing the same thing in my CSV file the code would work but unfortunately it doesn't work either)

```
t = 1e-3 * np.array([3.524,7.06,10.608,14.17,17.744,21.326,24.918,28.518,32.128,35.746,39.372])
```

instead of

```
t = pd.read_csv("Fall.csv")   # Opening the data file
```

Do you know where the error can come from? I mean why does the code work when I enter the values manually but not when I try to read a file with exactly the same values? I specify that I have 11 data in my CSV file.

Here is my initial CSV file (i.e. without having added the values at each iteration) with name 'Fall.csv':

```
| 3.524 |
| 3.536 |
| 3.548 |
| 3.562 |
| 3.574 |
| 3.582 |
| 3.592 |
| 3.6   |
| 3.61  |
| 3.618 |
| 3.626 |
```

And here is my complete code :

```py
import numpy as np                    # For the calculation
import pandas as pd                   # To read files
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt       # To draw curves
import scipy.optimize as opt          # For the adjustment

# Raw data
t = pd.read_csv("Fall.csv")   # Opening the data file
z = -0.01 * np.linspace(1, 11, 11)

# Definition of the free fall function
g = 9.81                     # the acceleration of gravity

def f(t,t0,h0):        # Definition of the fitting function
    return -0.5*g*(t-t0)**2 + h0

# Data adjustment
init_param = [0 , 0]          # Initial values t0=0, h0=0
final_param , var = opt.curve_fit(f,t,z)

# Optimal function
tt = np.linspace(final_param[0], 100e-3,100)
hh = f(tt, *final_param) # Reconstruction of the fitted curve

# Plot of analyzed data
plt.clf()                           # Plot of data and fit
plt.xlabel("Time (s)")
plt.ylabel("Height (m)")
legend = "t0 = %f ms, h0 = %f centimeter " % (final_param[0]*1000,final_param[1]*100)
plt.plot(tt,hh,"r--",label=legend)     # The adjustment
plt.plot(t,z,"bo", label="Data")     # The data
plt.legend()
```

Comment: What do you mean by reshaping the data?

Comment: Please [provide code and data as text, not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @SibtainReza that seems highly unlikely since the code at least has the problem that it doesn't ignore the .csv header and the size will be off by one.

Comment: @SibtainReza then that's what you should have said in the first place, since the problem here is that OP should have passed `t[0]` where they are passing `t` to `op.curve_fit` - saying you just got it to work as is while you did something else that avoided the problem OP mentioned is unhelpful and likely to turn others away from answering. Don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem arises from the shape of `t`.
Scipy `curve_fit`[documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) specifies that, in your case, `xdata`should a Sequence, ie a 1D array (more or less).

However, as your csv has one value by row, `pd.read_csv()` reads it as a DataFrame, which basically is a 2D array.

You can check it by printing `t.shape`, which outputs `(11,1)`, while `z.shape` is `(11,)`.

There are multiple solutions to this problem, either rewrite your csv on one line or call `opt_curve` with `t[0]` to pick only the first column of `t`. Careful here, `0` is the name of the first and only column of your DataFrame, and not an index. This gives would give : `final_param, var = opt.curve_fit(f, t[0], z)`

I would advise for the first solution though, to directly get the desired shape when reading the data.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations. I had already tried the first solution but it returned the same error message as the one I posted. As for the second solution, I get a "KeyError: 0" error.

Comment: This means that your dataframe does not have the same column names. 
Try to print `t.columns` and see what is the name of the column, that should replace 0 !